envoy TLS packets are missing
I have a successful connection established between two applications where Envoy is running as a sidecar in both of them. The connection between the two Envoys is in TLS. I am sure that the TLS connection is taking place, but I don't see any TLS packet in the PCAP file captured!
Also seeing ssl error occurred while read: WANT_READ error.

I am sure that the TLS connection is taking place Why are you sure? I don't see any TLS packet in the PCAP file captured! Well, how did you create this capture? Also seeing ssl error occurred while read: WANT_READ Where are you seeing this error? And finally, how is this a programming question?
